# most efficient method to filter a mix of character and numeric data in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

i have a list of orders with headers (ID, process, material, finish) and a dataset of machines. It has the headers (ID, process, materials, finishes). For each order i want to find the compatible machines.

I can create a list of list containing the orders and a list of list containing the  machines and use a for loop to finish this task. The code for the same is mentioned below. However, i want a more efficient method to do the same.

```
orders = [[1, 'cutting', 'Al', 200], [2, 'boring', 'Al', 200]]

machines = [[1, 'cutting', ['Steel', 'Al'], [100,200,300]], \
            [2, 'boring', ['titanium', 'PLA', 'ABS'], [100,200]], \
            [3, 'hobbing', ['wood', 'Al', 'SS'], [300,400]]]

match = []
for i in range(len(orders)):
    for j in range(len(machines)):
        if orders[i][1] == machines[j][1] and orders[i][2] in machines[j][2] and \
        orders[i][3] in machines[j][3]:
           match.append([orders[i][0], machines[j][0]])   

print (match)
```

I could not use a numpy array because material and resolution columns in machines consists of lists with different lengths and lists can't be an element in numpy array. please suggest what is a more efficient method to do this. i have hundred of orders and thousand of machines so this for loop method becomes highly inefficient.

Comment: This may be better for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) than StackOverflow since it is about optimizing your code and not debugging errors.

Comment: Please clarify: you tagged your question with `pandas` but I don't see `pandas` in your code.

Comment: @EdekiOkoh, don't recommend Code Review unless you are active on that board and prepared to write an answer.

Comment: With all due respect @hpaulj I disagree. I recommend it because the purpose of that [stack](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211788/code-review-vs-stackoverflow) is relevant to the OP's question and may get him a better answer than simply using SO. He probably didn't even know of the existence of that stack. Just because I do not know the answer doesn't mean I can't point the OP to a good direction to get an answer that might be relevant to him. But that is a discussion not meant for comments.

Comment: @EdekiOkoh, improving efficiency is a routine question for SO [numpy] problems, as people seek to replace iterative solutions with 'vectorized' ones.  This is tagged [numpy] so I suspect the OP has that kind of improvement in mind.  But he notes that using `numpy` will be difficult with this kind of data, and I agree.  As a pure Python problem it might get useful answers on CR.  Beware that CR tends to be pickier about the problem style and completeness.

Comment: @AlexYu i am open to solutions using pandas, numpy or any other library which can  improve efficiency. numpy and pandas is what i could think of what can be relevant here.

Comment: If you open for `pandas` solution: `pandas.DataFrame` allows filtering in style: `df[(df['material'] == 'Steel']) 
 & (df['process']=='boring)]`. Look at [examples](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/comparison/comparison_with_sql.html#where)

Comment: @AlexYu in my machines dataframe, material column has a list of materials. can i insert a list as an element in pandas df and then search for an element in that list?

Comment: @deep You can have store any type in pandas DataFrame. You can even have dataframes of dataframes

Comment: @AlexYu can you show me a small example using my case?

Comment: @hpaulj I understand your reasoning now. Thanks! I'll leave my comments up so give context to the discussion

Answer (score 1):

For a start we can clean up the iteration with:

```
for order in orders:
    for machine in machines:
        if order[1] == machine[1] and order[2] in machine[2] and \
        order[3] in machine[3]:
           match.append([order[0], machine[0]])
```

It may not make much difference in speed, but does make things more readable.

```
for order in orders:
    for machine in machines:
        if order[1] == machine[1] and \ 
           order[2] in machine[2] and \
           order[3] in machine[3]:
           match.append([order[0], machine[0]])
```

If `machines` are unique on `machine[1]`, it might help to make a dictionary

```
machine_dict = {machine[1]: [machine[0], machine[2], machine[3]] for machine in machines}
```

And in the loop:

```
for order ...
    machine = machine_dict[order[1]]
    # but what if there's a keyerror?
    # the rest of the test
```

If there are multiple machines with the same `[1]`, the dictionary will be more complicated, but might still be useful.